# How to open multiple viewer windows in Toad?

Tags: toad

Im sure this is pretty simple but I just cant seem to find the option.
My Toad MySql install only seems to allow me to have one "Viewer" window open and hence its impossible to view multiple tables - or have a window open for each table Im working with.
Does anyone know how to change this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Right click on table -> `Send to` -> `New window`. Table will open in new tab. Next, you can rearrange tabs to see them simultaneously: menu `Window` -> `New vertical tab group`. Checked in Toad for MySQL 4.5.